# Recyclerview scroll to specific position inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

Assume, I have 40 items in a RecyclerView and want to scroll to Item number 20

Here is how my XML looks like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/testRecyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Java code, I'm using in onCreate() to set adapter in a RecyclerView:

```
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            testRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            adapter = new ProductsAdapter(getActivity(), productModels);
            testRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In case of LinearLayout, it works very well, but doesn't when we use NestedScrollView

```
testRecyclerview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in my case

```
 testRecyclerview.post(() -> {
            float y = testRecyclerview.getY() + testRecyclerview.getChildAt(50).getY();
            nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) y);
        });
```

Comment: try this 

        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

in recycleview xml

Comment: what is 100 above (I mean what is offset)

Comment: It is spacing from top to recycleview item

Comment: tried with false for nestedScrollingEnabled in recyclerview, but did not work

Comment: Can you share your java file ? i will check my be there is some issue because in my case this will work

Comment: sure... I appreciate

Comment: please use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, just like my implementation